# Pulling many-many subtotals

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll try to explain this the best possible.  I'm working on a reservation software, and we were trying to add some more "flexibility" and now I've lost some functionality.

I'm dealing with rooms and room types.  Previously every time we made a new room feature, we created a standalone room type.  But then every time you added a feature, you had to create multiple new types, because one room could have multiple types and features.

Here's what the database looks like now:

```
rooms     roomTypes    roomType_Locker   roomFeatures   roomFeature_Locker
-----     ---------    ---------------   ------------   ------------------
rid       tid          tid               fid            fid 
rnum      tcode        rid               fcode          rid
<other>   <other>                        <other>       

groups    typeGroup_Locker     featureGroup_Locker   res         resFeatures
------    ----------------     -------------------   ---         -----------
gid       gid                  gid                   resid       resid
gname     tid                  fid                   startdate   fid
<other>   rid (normally null)                        enddate
```

I think the first row is pretty explanatory, rooms, roomTypes, roomFeatures and their "Lockers" as I call them.

A room can be multiple **types** and have multiple **features**.  For room features, every room as a "default" feature. (however i could get rid of that, it was just one way I could handle a query if there was always something in the feature database).

```
Examples of types:        Examples of features:
King Bed                  Default
Double Beds               OceanFront
Studio                    First Floor
Suite                     Remodeled
Any
```

Groups are how we display availability to internal employees.  It's simply a way to group room types and features for easier visibility.

So some examples of Groups:
Total  (This group would include all types--typeGroup_Locker would have an entry for every type-- and "default" currently--featureGroup_Locker would have gid and "default" feature only--)  I'm looking for just a total count of rooms available and in use
King Beds (This group would include only King Bed types, but ALL features).
OceanFront (This group would be all types, but only OceanFront feature).
etc...

The issue I'm having is I'm counting rooms more than once, I've tried about 25 different combinations of queries.

I can get the max # of each "group" fairly easily.  The difficulty is when I try to show "booked" vs "used".  Booked would be the # of rooms booked with that specific type & feature (features).  "used" would be if the room is used, but wasn't necessarily booked.

Here are some examples of my code:

This query grabs all the tids & fids for the "Group":

```
SELECT roomTypes.tcode, roomTypes.tid, 
                        roomFeatures.fcode, roomFeatures.fid
            FROM roomTypes
                JOIN roomTypeGroup_Locker ON roomTypes.tid = roomTypeGroup_Locker.tid
                LEFT JOIN roomFeaturesGroup_Locker ON roomFeaturesGroup_Locker.gid = roomTypeGroup_Locker.gid
                LEFT JOIN roomFeatures ON roomFeatures.fid = roomFeaturesGroup_Locker.fid
            WHERE roomTypeGroup_Locker.gid='{$gid}'
```

Then inside of that loop, I've been performing this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as the_count
    FROM res,
         rooms,
         roomTypes,
         roomType_Locker,
         roomTypeGroup_Locker,
         roomFeatures,
         roomFeatures_Locker,
         roomFeaturesGroup_Locker
WHERE res.startdate <= '$entry'
         AND res.enddate >= '$entry'
         AND res.rnum = rooms.rnum
         AND rooms.rid = roomType_Locker.rid
         AND roomType_Locker.tid = roomTypes.tid
         AND roomTypes.tid = roomTypeGroup_Locker.tid
         AND roomTypeGroup_Locker.gid = '{$gid}'
         AND res.tcode = '$tcode'
         AND res.tcode = roomTypes.tcode
         AND rooms.rid = roomFeatures_Locker.rid
         AND roomFeatures_Locker.fid = roomFeatures.fid
         AND roomFeatures.fid = roomFeaturesGroup_Locker.fid
         AND roomFeatures.fid = '{$fid}'
         AND roomFeaturesGroup_Locker.gid = roomTypeGroup_Locker.gid
```

What I am trying to do is determine the "USAGE" of types & features that match the group I am looking at.  Because someone could choose an "ANY" type, "OceanFront" feature.  That technically is a "King Bed", "OceanFront".

Is there an easier way to do this?  I'm to the point of thinking I'm going to have to store all the data in some form of array and do the processing locally.  When before I could get the data with just some SQL queries.

I'm looking for any guidance at this point, even if it means scrapping this and starting over.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `php`? I cannot see any PHP here...

Comment: I coded PHP, as the language I develop in is PHP.  These are just the SQL queries that bring the data in and PHP does all the processing.